# Issue with definition of adaptive control and its classification

Tags: adaptive-control

I have a question about the definition of adaptive control, since I´m researching about making a model-free adaptive control system. I will appreciate your help.
The definition I found says that an adaptive control modifies its parameters or structure in order to achieve a performance index. Reading about the subject in different sources I noticed that when they refer to an adaptive controller, it always has a model of the plant and implies an adaptation law which is usually obtained by taking the model and manipulating expressions.
My deduction is that when these sources refers to adaptive control, is about a kind of this instead. Am I right? I will really appreciate your support on this.
Thanks.
Pablo.

Comment: Adaptive control subsumes model free and model based...model based being the traditional one.